# when i run this code on browser ,toolbar appears at the bottom how can i make it on top of browser

Tags: vuetify.js

```css
<style scoped>
.toolb{
  position:absolute
  top:0px;
}
</style>
```

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        sideNav: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="sideNav">
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile>
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>supervisor_account</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>View Meetups</v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar dark class="primary toolb">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon
        @click.stop="sideNav = !sideNav"
        class="hidden-sm-and-up "></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>DevMeetup</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-xs-only">
        <v-btn flat>
          <v-icon left dark>supervisor_account</v-icon>
          View Meetups
        </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar>
    <main>

    </main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

to make toolbar on top i have to use css style ' position
:absloute ; top:0px;' that affect my all other components because i have to use again in all components style ' position
:absloute ; top:50px or 40 px;' and those components are not behaving like they should  so please tell how can i fix it ? without  using css style only vuetify
.where i study vuetify ,my teacher was using as it is code and its working fine without css ??? only using vuetify in this component .
but if i use v-content to parent of my v-container than i am getting another problem that is navigation-drawer is on top after that  toolbar is appearing

Comment: you are showing none of your CSS which would most likely be responsible for the position. Also, what have you tried so far to achieve what you want?

Comment: Can you provide a CodePen or a JsFiddle reproducing your issue plz ? Here's a template with vue and vuetify https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/bgJOrX

Comment: i have added  css . which i have used to achieve toolbar on top of document

Comment: hello toodoo in my earlier code i have not used v-content as parent of v-container but when i use it .navigation-drawer is on top after that toolbar is appearing i have tried it into codepen